# Problem with angular HttpClient.get method

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-httpclient, passport-jwt

I am implementing passport-jwt for route protection on my MEAN Stack pet-project.
The server side is working good, server receives the correct jwt in headers and responds correctly for postman requests and requests from my angular app while I use full url in get request.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
...
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
...
getProfile() {
  this.loadToken();
  let requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'text')
    .append('Authorization', this.authToken);
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/users/profile', {headers: requestHeaders})
}
```

But when I remove my localhost domain from the request url to prepare the app for hosting, I start to receive

> error 401 Unauthorized

```
return this.http.get('users/profile', {headers: requestHeaders})
```

I logged to console the headers from both request and notice that they are completely different

[image: headers of first (full url) request],
[image: headers of second request]

In the first request (which works normally) I have my jwt in `[[Entries]]` array, but in second request it's in `lazyUpdate`  array and server can't find it.
Why headers changing so drastically only by removing localhost from url? How to fix this headers?

P.S. [my passport configuration](https://github.com/dterelia/ACapp/blob/master/config/passport.js)

Answer (score 0):

seems like the issue occurs from your passport.js

you have used

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT') // this method no longer supports by the newer versions of the passport js
```

so as for your passport js implementation try this. also note in here give a check
**jwt_payload._id** object with your implementation because in the passport js official documentation their implementation cannot give you that id of the session data..

User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id, (err, user) => {} // in this code check the above mentioned one

as for the second step try this,

```
var opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    // opts.issuer = config.issuer;
    // opts.audience = config.audience;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,function(jwtPayload,done){   
        User.getUserById(jwtPayload.id,function(err,profile){
            if(err){
                return done(err,false);
            }
            if(profile){
                return done(null,profile);
            }else{
                return done(null,false);
            }
        });
    }));
```